# Regenerate XCFramework if there is a code change

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I have a Demo project and Framework which can be integrated with multiple ways(Cocoapods, SPM - using generated XCFramework, directly integrate with XCFramework)

For distributing Demo app to external users we integrate the Framework with SPM.

Problem with this approch is during development its makes really hard to regenerate XCFramework after each change, so I have decided to drag and drop the Framework's project to Demo app, but cant understand how to recompile XCFramework if there is a change.
Could you please help me with understading how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `.xcworkspace` that contains the framework project and the demo app project side by side, then inside the demo app target General settings (see screenshot), add the `.framework` file from the framework project within the workspace instead of depending on the `.xcframework` binary file directly.

[image]

After that, add a "Copy File" build phase that embeds the framework file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems like it does not work
I have created .workspace and added both .xcodeproj (Demo and Framework), but Frameworks folder for Framework is empty, only in Products folder there is a Framework.framework, and when I am adding this, actually framework is missing and showing as a red in Demo app's Frameworks folder(sorry cant attach the pics)

Comment: I've edited the answer and tested the solution and it works for me, can you try adding the build phase that copies and embeds the framework file?

Comment: I had another issue, but seems like its working for now
Thanks a lot